# How can I create a dropwizard (jersey) resource which accepts a nullable representation?

Tags: jersey, dropwizard

I am trying to create an action on a resource within dropwizard which accepts a representation, but allows this to be null, ie. no post data from the client.

Currently, from a client, I have to post "{}" otherwise an HTTP 415, unsupported media type is returned. I assume this is because my client is not sending a content-type header as content-length = 0.

I tried to define the resources as follows, but get a "Producing media type conflict" back from jersey as both methods consume the same path and jersey cannot differentiate between them:

```
@Path("/interview")
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
@Log
class InterviewResource {

    @POST
    @Timed
    Interview advanceNewInterview() {

        // some processing...
    }

    @POST
    @Timed
    Enquiry advanceNewInterview(@Valid AdvanceInterviewRepresentation advanceInterview) {

        // some processing...
    }
}
```

Any ideas on how to represent this?

Comment: Can you try dropping the @Consumes annotation. Hacky but might work.

Answer (score 0):

You could use Optional for your parameter as show below:

```
@POST
@Timed 
Enquiry advanceNewInterview(@Valid Optional<AdvanceInterviewRepresentation> advanceInterview)
{
  if (advanceInterview.isPresent())
  { 
      // some processing...
  } 
}
```

Howerver the main Reason for 415 is not mentioning the Content-Type header. In your case it should be Content-Type : application/json